# R, rvest and selectorGadget on Facebook

Tags: html, r, facebook, web-scraping, rvest

I've got problem with rvest on Facebook. I've webscraped many things by R earlier, so I understand how for example `html_nodes` works. I always use SelectorGadget and everything workes. This time, SelectorGadget doesn't work on Facebook site so I have to cope with html.

Let's say I've got this site https://www.facebook.com/avanti/posts/1017920341583065 and I want to extract article title ('Karnawałowe stylizacje F&F'). How can I do it?

I've tried so far:

```
library("rvest")

link_fb <- "http://www.fb.com/103052579736517_1017920341583065"

html_strony <- read_html(link_fb)
html_text(html_nodes(html_strony, "mbs _6m6"))
```

but it doesn't work. I'd be really greatfull for any help.

PS I have to have this title, not after clicking the link, because it could be different there.

Comment: I see now that SelectorGadget works on Chrome (I was testing it earlier on Firefox only). But unfortunetly even SelectorGadget  can't help...

Comment: if my answer siuts you, you can confirm it

Answer (score 1):

I think you should USE Facebook API to download content and information from Facebook: `Rfacebook` R package and Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com/
You can write your own R-Facebook-API conection with `httr` package. Good luck

Comment: Marcin! I did what you suggested and I managed to get some information about this site. Everything but the information I need (this title on the image)... Could you propose some more detailed instrucions maybe?

Comment: I think this might be imposible sińce this is not at a standalone text but an embded image. There is No separate text there.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... My only hope was that it is possible to see this title in a pure html of this site. Thanks anyway.